# create a timestamp from month and year string columns in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I want to create a timestamp column to create a line chart from two columns containing month and year respectively.
The df looks like this:
I know I can create a string concat and then convert it to a datetime column:

`df.select('*',
           concat('01', df['month'],
                     df['year']).alias('date')).withColumn("date", 
                                                            df['date'].cast(TimestampType()))`

But I wanted a cleaner approach using an inbuilt PySpark functionality that can also help me create other date parts, like week number, quarters, etc. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to concatenate the string once, make the `timestamp` type column and then you can easily extract `week`, `quarter` etc.

You can use this function (and edit it to create whatever other columns you need as well):

```
def spark_date_parsing(df, date_column, date_format):
    """
    Parses the date column given the date format in a spark dataframe
    NOTE: This is a Pyspark implementation

    Parameters
    ----------
    :param df: Spark dataframe having a date column
    :param date_column: Name of the date column
    :param date_format: Simple Date Format (Java-style) of the dates in the date column

    Returns
    -------
    :return: A spark dataframe with a parsed date column
    """
    df = df.withColumn(date_column, F.to_timestamp(F.col(date_column), date_format))
    # Spark returns 'null' if the parsing fails, so first check the count of null values
    # If parse_fail_count = 0, return parsed column else raise error
    parse_fail_count = df.select(
        ([F.count(F.when(F.col(date_column).isNull(), date_column))])
    ).collect()[0][0]
    if parse_fail_count == 0:
        return df
    else:
        raise ValueError(
            f"Incorrect date format '{date_format}' for date column '{date_column}'"
        )
```

Usage (with whatever is your resultant date format):

`df = spark_date_parsing(df, "date", "dd/MM/yyyy")`